# scala widening of method signatures

Tags: scala

I have a class written that expects to be given an `Option[(E) => Long]`:

```
class Whatever[E] (sizeFunction: Option[(E) => Long])
```

When I try and instantiate it with a function `(E) => Int`:

```
val sizeFunction = (a: String) => a.length
new Whatever[String](Some(sizeFunction))
```

i get a compilation error:

```
type mismatch;
found   : String => Int
required: String => Long
```

Shouldnt `String => Int` "satisfy" `String => Long` due to widening?

Comment: `... a.length.toLong`, `a.length` returns `Int`. Or if you want to use conversion: `val sizeFunction : (String => Long) =`, type is inferred at the point you define `sizeFunction`

Comment: i realize a.length is `String => Int`, however, since every `Int` is a `Long`, I expected my code above to compile.

Comment: Implicit conversions only apply to `Int` => `Long`, not to `String => Int` => `String => Long`, also statement "`Int` is a `Long`" is wrong, `Int` is not a subclass of `Long`

Comment: @radai `since every Int is a Long, I expected` -- No. Int is not a subtype of Long. They can be *converted* to Long, but that's not an OO is-a inheritance relationship

Comment: @Daenyth yes, there's no inheritance defined. I was referring to what Alexey called "week conformance" below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind String => Int is a type in and of itself. String => Long is a different type. This is important to some programs and not important to others, as in your example. But it would be dangerous for the compiler to make assumptions and not call out type mismatches because it could possibly widen one part of a function type. If you really care you can define sizeFunction as String => Number.

Comment: but i'm aggregating and keeping track of those `Long`s. lugging around `Number`s would make my life considerably harder

Comment: What if you defined sizeFunction as

```
val sizeFunction: String => Long = (a: String) => a.length
```

Comment: definitely better than a.length.toLong. i still think it should be theoretically safe to apply widening conversions here, but this is the answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, functions are *covariant* in their return type: for `A => B` to be a subtype of `A => C`, `B` must be a subtype of `C`. But `Int` is not a subtype of `Long` (i.e. it isn't true that "every `Int` is a `Long`"); instead it can be widened to `Long`, which is a different relation.

Definition of covariance probably *could* be changed to say that `B` must *weakly conform* to `C` instead (i.e. `B` is a subtype of `C`, or can be widened to `C`, or there is a chain of intermediate types between `B` and `C` for which one of the above holds). But then for consistency the same would have to apply to contravariance: `Long => A` would be a subtype of `Int => A` (by applying widening to the argument). This doesn't seem like a good idea to me (and changing only covariance, but not contravariance, seems even worse).

Comment: i actually see no harm in allowing `Long => A` where `Int => A` is required (apart from the overhead of a widening conversion), but its a theoretical argument at this point :-)